# How to check if new rows is insert in specific table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My table name is pm. I have two questions.

1. How can I check if new rows is insert this table(using wpdb query)?
2. How to get the inserted rows from table (using wpdb query)?

Comment: you may use `$wpdb->insert()` for Q1. `$wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM myTable" );` for Q2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$wpdb->insert('table', $arrayData);
```

this will return true if it successfully added to your table and false if failed to add to table due to some error in query

to get the last inserted record id you can use

```
$wpdb->insert_id
```

which will return last record's id

more details on $wpdb is here
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row